# Random sound from my own DB

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i create a DB sqlite with DB browser.
I need to start an randomized audio from my Db.
The table is "audio" with 4 field (Id, audio , col2, col3)
I put in "audio" field the R.raw.nameaudio.

this is the random number:

```
       rand = new Random();
       int random=rand.nextInt(4)+1;
```

this is the query:

```
    public Cursor cont(Integer ID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select audio from audio where ID= "+ID, null);
    return res; }
```

Now i need to start MediaPlayer but it does not work.

this is the rest of the code:

```
       Cursor res = mDBHelper.controllo(random);
                    while (res.moveToNext()) {
                        int audio = res.getInt(0);
                        stopPlaying();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audio);
                        mp.start();

                    }
```

There is a problem with second argument of mediaplayer.create.
I cant pass the right data type. How i can fix this?

Thank you so much.

EDIT:
i try to put only "nameaudio" in the field "audio". After i insert:

```
                int audio = getResources().getIdentifier(res.getString(0), 
                                                   "raw", "mypackage");
                                                 stopPlaying();

                  mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audio);
                        mp.start();
```

Now i listn the audio but after some click the app crash.

Comment: Why not just selecting a random row? `... ORDER BY RANDOM LIMIT 1`

Comment: try "int audio = res.getInt(1);" because you said that you have 4 fields  (Id, audio , col2, col3) so "audio" is on index "1";

Comment: @Rotwang You are right but the problem remains and i need to eliminate the row after the start of sound.

Comment: @aksacha nope because the cursor return only one column

Answer (score 0):

After getting the random number

Try something like this:

```
    int aud1 = R.raw.my_audio_1;
    int aud2 = R.raw.my_audio_2;
    int aud3 = R.raw.my_audio_3;
    int aud4 = R.raw.my_audio_4;

    int audioToPlay = -1;
    switch (random){
        case 1:
            audioToPlay = aud1;
            break;
        case 2:
            audioToPlay = aud1;
            break;
        case 3:
            audioToPlay = aud1;
            break;
        case 4:
            audioToPlay = aud1;
            break;
    }
    // now simply assign this audio to media player

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),audioToPlay);
    mp.start();
```

Comment: I need the solution with DB, because i have 100 or more sound.